# ElasticSearch - How to treat missing fields as 0 when sorting by field?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing

I am trying to sort by a `double` field, called `ranking` that is not fully populated. If I try to sort by the `ranking` field, the fields that don't have a `ranking` value are treated as `Infinity`.

I am already aware that you can treat missing fields as `_first` or `_last` when sorting. But Is there a way to treat the missing values of a field as `0` when sorting by field?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can use [sort script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sort-search-results.html#script-based-sorting) in this case.

```
POST idx_my/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name":"A", "ranking": 20.0 }
{"index":{}}
{"name":"B", "ranking": null }

POST idx_my/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "sort": {
      "_script": {
         "script": "if(doc['ranking'].size() == 0) { return 0.0; } else { return doc['ranking'].value; }",
         "type": "number",    
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```